Thread stops printing out after main function returns in JUnit
I couldn't find the right answer for my question.
I'm going to find a way to test my code (using JUnit) and see result in eclipse console. After some investigations it turns out that setDaemon(true) for a thread will keeps the thread working while the main method return but noting is shown in the console that shows new thread is working. So, here is the situation:
I have a webservice that create an object and return its ID to a user but I would like to do another thing after the return statement.
I have used a new thread but due to that my function takes time, at first return statement is called, as a result the new thread (firstThread) never finishes! I appreciate any advice.
I don't want to use join() for my thread because it will stop user from getting result from webservice until my job is done!
here are sample code:
 @Test
    public void tt() {
        System.out.println("Start main thread.");

        Thread firstThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            //never saw in eclipse console 
            System.out.println("First thread is running.");
        });

        Thread secondThread = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Second thread is running.");
        });

        try {
        firstThread.setDaemon(true); // 
        secondThread.start();
        firstThread.start();

        System.out.println("both done");
        return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

in this example I never see "First thread is running." below are the output appeared in the console:
Start main thread.
both done
Second thread is running.

What do you believe firstThread.setDaemon(true) does, and do you actually want that to be the case?

(It's pretty unclear what the context is here, mind you... how is this code being executed?)

I have used both firstThread.setDaemon(true) as well as commenting it out but nothing changed.
@JonSkeet I am running this code as a JUnit but never saw the "First thread is running." in the console.. Am I wrong waiting to see the result in the console?

I don't know what JUnit does with the console when threads are running in the background, and you haven't shown us anything about how you're testing your code. (You haven't included a method declaration, or a test etc.) Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question to provide much more context.

If you paste your example into jshell it all works fine. It looks like JUNIT is cleaning up the unterminated threads (does not matter whether daemon or not). As this is a JUNIT test why not add join so that you can validate results? A better way would use CompletableFuture or similar so that the caller can check the results later.

setDaemon(true) works fine on server but I was looking for a way to check it in a test. @DuncG propose a practical way. Thanks!

This question is nothing to do with daemon threads so should not be closed as a duplicate of "What is a daemon thread in Java? "

Multithreading in unit tests is a bit tricky, as the jUnit runner will only know about your main thread, and once that returns the jUnit runner will consider the test as completed. Other threads might keep running in the background (potentially interfering with other tests), but once the last test has been executed then jUnit considers its job done and exits.
So what happens here is that your test method is initiated, it spawns two threads and then returns. JUnit only sees a test that has run without any exceptions, marks the test case green and calls it a day.
Usually when working with multiple threads in unit tests, I create some way of checking if threads other than the main one are done before exiting the test. Has mainly been an issue in integration tests (@SpringBootTest) in my experience though.
I'm also a bit unsure on where System.out.println actually end up when done from a daemon thread where the main thread is no longer there, could be that they end up "nowhere".
If you are using Spring, you should check out the @Async annotation to simplify your code. Do note that any errors will happen outside the "scope" of the caller, and won't be noticable, so you would need to take extra care with error handling. Using a message bus could be a way of ensuring that all invocations are handled, but it might also be overkill. With Spring async the code should look something like:
public class WebService {
    private SomeAsyncService someAsyncService;

    public Something webMethod(final int id) {
        final Something something = findSomethingAndDoStuffThatDoesntTakeMuchTime(id);

        someAsyncService.doStuffThatTakesALotOfTime(something);
        return something;
    }
}

public class SomeAsyncService {
    @Async
    public void doStuffThatTakesALotOfTime(final Something something) {
        try {
            // do stuff
            // can take time
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // error handling based on your needs
        }
    }
}

For a caller of webMethod, it will only need to wait for the first invocation, and return while another trade is doing the doStuffThatTakesALotOfTime method.
